# Cost-wise, what's the best approach to hosting a very high traffic server?

Tags: traffic

I have a server that generates a high traffic amount from unique content (live video chat), and need to be able to handle UL traffic of about 500-1000 TB per month, but have relatively low CPU needs (limited processing requirement due to the architecture).

I'm looking for a way to do this through a 3rd party without totally breaking the bank (e.g. this would cost $50-100k/month at AWS). I know very little about the market and am looking for help to start. I saw Estoxy offers 1PB traffic for €300/month for 500TB and €500/month for 1000TB, and while this company has no reputation whatsoever, it makes me optimistic that there are options for doing this that are substantially lower cost than AWS.

Are there any good options to explore?

Comment: Note that actual product recommendations are considered off topic

Answer (score 1):

If you’re not tied to the AWS because of your application design and use of other cloud services  in general your options are

- on-premise (requires a suitable internet connection and a server room for your hardware would be nice)
- rent space at a commercial data center : a **co-location** facility where you rent space to house your own server hardware (in a shared 19 inch server cabinet, your own private 1/4 1/3 1/2 or full server cabinet or your own suite) and buy bandwidth either directly from the co-location provider or select your own ISP when the facility is carrier neutral and has an isp break out room.
- Rent a **dedicated server** which includes both the server hardware, power and bandwidth.
- Rent a **managed server** which includes both the server hardware, power, bandwidth and a system administrator performing (basic) installation and ongoing management tasks
- rather than a full physical server you can have the options above as virtual servers

All options above are frequently offered with either 100/1.000/10.000 Mbit/s uplinks with unmetered bandwidth and/or large traffic packages.